# Hex editors for Windows?

Tags: windows, hex-editor

Are there some hex editors for Windows? Preferably open source or free since I don't need a hex editor all that often...

Things I do need is the ability to search in different types (text, raw hex, little endian short, big endian short, etc.) and viewing by type (same as searching types) starting at the selected byte. It would be nice to be able to create structs on the fly, so I can view binary blobs in the file. Binary file comparison is also a must, hopefully it would be smart and enable block detection.

I do know about [the list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors), but I don't really have time to try the 60 or hex editors, and I was wondering what other people use.

Comment: For the record, the same thing asked on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426/what-is-a-good-windows-hex-editor-viewer

Comment: The SO question isn't there anymore. Some of the best questions around here seem to be closed !?

Comment: @Liviu - Yes, it is a shame. I have no idea why that particular question was removed. Marking a question as [Closed] is one thing, but removing it (and any existing answers) is another matter, and and it seems to me to be a bit excessive except in cases of abuse (spam, etc...).

Comment: For some reason, every time I think "oh, that's exactly the question I was looking for" it appears to be closed...

Comment: @ArturKlesun it's like when you google something and all the results for similar questions are just full of people saying to Google it.

Comment: I would advice, https://freehexeditorneo.com

Comment: Can SU please reopen this question? It this should be archived or deleted, it's all extremely outdated...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[Free Hex Editor (frhed)](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/), small and fast.

[image]

Comment: +1. I like the fact that it doesn't require an installer. Also, it is open source.

Comment: No drag-and-drop.

Comment: looooove it so good

Comment: This question is closed but obviously active: If you like "native" stuff, `List.exe` comes with the Windows 2K3 Toolkit, & is both a binary & hex editor. The `list.exe /?` help command doesn't give much info, but once inside the editor just hit ? to see commands. `H` opens the Hex editor, & `F1` toggles the way the Hex is displayed

Comment: @Liviu Just downloaded Frhed 1.6.0 and dragging-and-dropping from Windows Explorer works.

Comment: Unfortunately, finding hex data is not straight forward... check first answer of the [FAQ](http://www.unrealtexture.com/Unreal/Website/Downloads/3DEditing/UnrealEditor/Tools/Info/frhed_v11/frhed-faq.txt) for help.

Comment: I know this is an old post but the download links on the page do not work. Also, the last stable release was back in 2009. I'm not sure if nine years old software works under current windows versions.

Comment: @TeoCarter It does. I'm using it on Windows 10 and used in Windows 7 way before - it works perfectly with all the drag-and-drop feature as opposed to Liviu answer. It also works fine under Wine.

Comment: Its a bad hex-editor, cant load 4gb files even if you have 18gb ram free.

Comment: It has no Undo/Redo function which is a huge miss.

Answer (score 65):

Personally, I use [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) (Free but not open source). Particular features of note include the ability to open very very large files, and you can modify raw disk data and open and edit data in RAM.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: HxD is a great free Hex Editor that handles massive files with ease. Definitely gets a +1 from me.

Comment: i like the feature to copy some data as a c,c#,pascal, java array ...

Comment: The wikipedia link is lame (and already in the question), please remove it for my vote!

Comment: does it provide option to disable disk edit? I worried my kid accidentally do it

Answer (score 14):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html) has a hex editor mode:

[image]

For an old school DOS style display, [ZTreeWin](http://www.ztree.com/html/ztreewin.htm):

[image]

(neither are free / open source).

Answer (score 14):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) with a [hex editor plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/). I was already using the text editor, so this makes for one less application installed.

[image]

Comment: This plugin is flaky in my experience.  It struggles with large files and switches to/from Hex mode at random.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't do much hex editing so I don't have much experience with it.

Comment: It's not useful when you want to edit a big file that doesn't fit on memory.

Answer (score 12):

[XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) is a freeware hex editor running under Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows NT, Windows 2000, and Windows XP.

[Cygnus Hex Editor](http://www.softcircuits.com/downloads.aspx) is a powerful file editor for Microsoft Windows. Unlike text editors, which are designed to edit files that contain text data, hex editors allow you to edit files that contain any type of data.

[Free Hex Editor Neo](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/Products/home/hex-editor-free.html) is award-winning large files optimized freeware editor for everyone who works with ASCII, hex, decimal, float, double and binary data.

[HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is a carefully designed and fast hex editor which, additionally to raw disk editing and modifying of main memory (RAM), handles files of any size.

Comment: No offense, but have you actually used any of these editors?  I appreciate the work that goes in to googling and pasting the copy from the websites, but I was looking for recommendations from actual usage.

Comment: I used the cygnus hex editor . But other i know one .. But those i didnt used . But i have tried Free Hex Editor very long back . That also good

Comment: I was coming here to suggest XVI32, so upvote for that

Answer (score 9):

[PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) can edit in hex, and it's free too.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Since I can hexedit in [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) as well, I tend to say ... Vim!

[image]

(Though I usually use [HxD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HxD).)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you turn hex edit mode on in Vim?

Comment: @KrisErickson: `:%!xxd`

Comment: NOT a true hex editor.

Comment: @Joshua: define "true hex-editor".

Comment: Editing either side changes the bytes.

Comment: kch kch kch. 2x.

Comment: use xxd reverse mode to change hex back to bytes eg. xxd -r

Comment: This depends on the external tool `xxd` which doesn't exist on Windows by default

Comment: Like vim which also does not exist in Windows by default...

Comment: Do any external hex tools exist on Windows by default?  I figured the lack thereof is why the question was being asked...

Answer (score 5):

[Winhex](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/) is a decent tool for that.

[image]

This is [a Stack Overflow version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426/what-is-a-good-windows-hex-editor-viewer) of the same question. There are a few more options so you can pick from the several recommended there if you do not like Winhex.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a hex editor that works from the command line, I like [Hexciting](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexciting/).

Comment: Seems to be a dead project - no activity since 09, link to wiki is 404