# Changing 2 bytes in a 16GB file - Hex editor or other recommendation needed

Tags: windows, hex-editor

I'm looking to change 2 bytes in the header of a 16GB file on windows 7.

I'm looking for a freeware solution to do this task once.

I have tried a few hex editors from the [superuser hex editor](https://superuser.com/questions/14465/hex-editors-for-windows) as well
as the [wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors) of hex editors.

Can anyone recommend a hex editor or similar program that allows to change
single bytes on very large files?

Comment: You could probably do this with a few lines of code in written in the Python language (which is free). It probably also true of some of the languages the come with Windows.

Comment: You can split the file to a small part with the header and the remainder using this sort of tools - http://www.hjsplit.org/, modify the header and then re-merge them using copy/b command. But I believe that there are many tools to hex big files directly so please consider this way if you can't find a better way.

Comment: recommendations should be on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) allows you to edit huge files directly (without having to load them). It has built-in hex editor.

Be careful or make a copy of file when using direct editing, since there are no backups.

Program is not freeware but for a one time procedure you can use trial version, which you can uninstall later.

Comment: Thanks, the solution works. I'll wait for a few days if someone recommends a free tools that does this too, before I mark this solved.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [tiny hexer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/tiny-hexer.shtml). I also use [HexEdit](http://www.catch22.net/software/hexedit) because it has a 64-bit version